# I need help with /testfor command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So my game is Hide And Seek and I have to start each round and end each round all the time. I suck at `/testfor` so I need help. I want it so that when 0 players are on the in-game team, then the seeker wins automatically. I tried many different things. The team name for the in-game people is `Player`, so I tried this:

```
testfor @a[Player_player_amount=0]
```

but it didn't work. What is wrong with it?

Comment: This question is answered here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303687/is-there-a-way-to-test-for-the-number-of-players-on-a-team-in-minecraft

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for testing for players with at least some scoreboard objective value is such:

```
/testfor @a[score_objective_min=0]
```

,where `objective` is the name of your objective, and `0` is the minimal value (in whole numbers) that one of the the players must have.

I assume you objective is named `player` (with a small 'p'). The command would then be:

```
/testfor @a[score_player_min=0]
```