# Is there a way to test for the number of players on a team in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make command block code that will testfor when there is only one player left on a score board team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `/testfor` command is run, the command block's `SuccessCount` tag will be set equal to the number of entities that the selector found. You can then use a `/testforblock` command in another block to check whether the first command block's `SuccessCount` is a certain number.

For example:

```
/testfor @a[team=red]
/testforblock X Y Z command_block -1 {SuccessCount:1}
```

Change `X Y Z` in the second command block to the coordinates of the first command block. You may also need to change `command_block` to `chain_command_block` or `repeating_command_block`.

The second command will only succeed if the first command has a `SuccessCount` of `1` (it found exactly 1 player). You can then run a conditional chain block off of that second command to activate whatever you want to happen when there are exactly 1 player:

[image: Setup]